# Returning string to _Layout.cshtml using PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to return a string list to a navigation menu that appears on the side of my _Layout.cshtml page. I can return a string fine, but I'm supposed to be returning a PartialViewResult. This is the error I get:

> {"The partial view 'Menu' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:\r\n~/Views/Nav/Menu.aspx\r\n~/Views/Nav/Menu.ascx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Menu.aspx\r\n~/Views/Shared/Menu.ascx\r\n~/Views/Nav/Menu.cshtml\r\n~/Views/Nav/Menu.vbhtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/Menu.cshtml\r\n~/Views/Shared/Menu.vbhtml"}

My Controller code:

```
using SportsStore.Domain.Abstract;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SportsStore.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class NavController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;

        public NavController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

        public PartialViewResult Menu()
        {
            IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
                                        .Select(x => x.Category)
                                        .Distinct()
                                        .OrderBy(x => x);

            return PartialView(categories);
        }
    }
}
```

My _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row panel">
        <div id="categories" class="col-xs-3">
            @Html.Action("Menu", "Nav")
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your Menu view located?

If you don't explicitly define what your View is called, MVC will take the initiative and assume it's named the same as your Action, so in this case, you need to have a `Menu.cshtml` file in one of the following locations :

- `~/Views/Nav/Menu.cshml`
- `~/Views/Shared/Menu.cshtml`

Or if it is named anything other than `Menu.cshtml`, you may want to consider specifying that within your code :

```
// This assumes your partial view is named "_Menu.cshtml"
return PartialView("_Menu",categories);
```

Comment: There is no Menu view. I wanted the HTML string to be passed back into my _Layout.cshtml so it would display in my Navigation menu along the left side of the screen. I'm working thru a Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book.

Comment: If you are using the `Html.Action()` call within your View, then the action that you are pointing to will be expected to render something to your View. I would expect since you are passing a collection of objects in, your View should probably consist of a loop iterating through your categories and outputting an item for each of them. Regardless, you'll want to create a View similar to that and ensure it is in the proper location to see that it renders at the expected position. You could even change your Action to return `Content("Example");` to see an example of this.

Comment: The Html.Action() in my View points to the Action Method in my Controller. When that Action Method returns a string, it can display it fine. It seems to know how to find the _Layout.cshtml. But when that Action Method returns a PartialViewResult, then MVC wants to find a different View file(one with same name as method) instead of the _Layout.cshtml.

Comment: The layout is going to be used regardless since you are returning a Partial View (MVC will know that and will only output what it needs to replace your `Html.Action()` call). If you create a view at one of the locations that I mention that looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/Rionmonster/45de461893600864f606dac575100e41) and place a loop to iterate through your items, you should see that it works.

Comment: You are correct. The book I was following had a small mistake. In the next chapter, it had me create a Menu.cshtml file and then it all rendered fine.

Answer (score 0):

@Rion Willimas, you are correct. The book I was following had a small mistake. In the next chapter, it had me create a Menu.cshtml file and then it all rendered fine. 
Menu.cshtml below:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@Html.ActionLink("Home", "List", "Product", null,
    new { @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"})

@foreach (var link in Model)
{
    @Html.RouteLink(link, new
{
    controller = "Product",
    action = "List",
    category = link,
    page = 1
}, new
{
    @class = "btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg"
})
}
```